# name conflicts of .so file in android binary

Tags: bazel

I'm linking a `cc_library` to an `android_binary` and getting a naming issue. Can someone tells me how to solve it?

The `cc_library`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "native_library",
    srcs = glob(["libs/**/*.so"])
)
```

The contents of libs directory:

```
libs
├── armeabi
│   ├── libSound.so
│   ├── libSec.so
│   ├── libWatch.so
│   └── libTec.so
├── armeabi-v7a
│   ├── libSound.so
│   ├── libSec.so
│   └── libWatch.so
├── x86
│   ├── libSound.so
│   ├── libSec.so
│   ├── libWatch.so
│   └── libTec.so
|—— other jars
```

And The error messages are like this:

```
ERROR: /the/path/to/BUILD:10:1: in android_binary rule //:debug_apk: Each library in the transitive closure must have a unique basename to avoid name collisions when packaged into an apk, but two libraries have the basename 'libSound.so': libs/armeabi/libSound.so and libs/armeabi-v7a/libSound.so.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but it's the limitation of apk layout, so I'm afraid you just cannot have that named libs in a fat apk. Is renaming libs into libSound-armeabi.so etc an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach that takes advantage of android_binary's --fat_apk_cpu flag and does not require renaming your libraries:

android_binary will build each cc_library once for each architecture specified by --fat_apk_cpu. The default of --fat_apk_cpu is just armeabi-v7a. This is known as the "Android split transition". When it builds each cc_library, that cc_library gets passed a --cpu flag from the list in --fat_apk_cpu. We can define config_setting rules that read these flags, and use a select statement in the cc_library, so that your cc_library contains different .so files depending on which architecture that it is built for.

For example:

```
# BUILD
CPUS = ["armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"]
[config_setting(name = cpu, values = {"cpu": cpu}) for cpu in CPUS]

cc_library(
    name = "native_library",
    srcs = select(
        {":%s" % cpu : glob(["libs/%s/*.so" % cpu]) for cpu in CPUS}
    ),
)

android_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    deps = [":native_library"],
)
```

And then on the command line you can specify which architectures you want present in the final APK.

```
$ bazel build --fat_apk_cpu=armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86 //:app
$ zipinfo -1 bazel-bin/app.apk | grep \.so$
lib/x86/libWatch.so
lib/x86/libSound.so
lib/x86/libSec.so
lib/x86/libTec.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libWatch.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libSound.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libSec.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libTec.so
lib/armeabi/libWatch.so
lib/armeabi/libSound.so
lib/armeabi/libSec.so
lib/armeabi/libTec.so

$ bazel build --fat_apk_cpu=x86 //:app
$ zipinfo -1 bazel-bin/app.apk | grep \.so$
lib/x86/libWatch.so
lib/x86/libSound.so
lib/x86/libSec.so
lib/x86/libTec.so
```

Specifying only one architecture to build for can speed up your development builds. For example, if you use an x86 emulator while you develop, you don't need the armeabi and armeabi-v7a .so files.